# QGIS WCS Could not understand response

Tags: qgis, wms, wcs

I am new to QGIS/GIS.

I'm trying to add a WMS source from the state of Minnesota to a project, just to test some things out (find the link here https://imageserver.gisdata.mn.gov/cgi-bin/wmswm?) I went Layer>Add Layer>WCS, and then added the link in the appropriate field. When I hit the "connect" button to access the data, an error message appears that reads as follows:

```
Could not understand the response:
Download of capabilities failed: The specified configuration cannot be used.
```

I've played around with the available configuration settings, and nothing seems to work.

I've tried it using the appropriate service (WMS/WMTS), and that I got the same error. Additionally, it seems to throw the error for any WMS that I try to add.

Comment: WMS and WCS are different services.

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to add that I had tried it using the WMS/WMTS option, and got the same result

Comment: using wms?VERSION=1.3.0&SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities QGIS will pull all the available images see answer.

Comment: fyi there is a how to at https://www.mngeo.state.mn.us/chouse/wms/how_to_use_wms.html

Comment: I had no problem loading layers in QGIS using the URL you provided. If you don't provide more information about what you are doing and how, it's impossible to see where the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

In QGIS (QGIS 3.30 used here) use the WMS URL

```
https://imageserver.gisdata.mn.gov/cgi-bin/wms?VERSION=1.3.0&SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if another URL solves the problem. I used the initial URL OP provided and could open layers in QGIS as well as in Google Earth. So the URL does not seem to be the problem. As OP mentions in comments, they used WMS service without result. So seems to be a more basic problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same mysterious error message for WMS URLs that worked before (qgis 3.22.4 on Linux). A restart of QGIS solved the problem for me.